# Closing DB handles on nested mongo queries in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am trying to run this nested query:

```
db.collection('a').find().each(function(i) {
  db.collection('b').find(... use i here ...).toArray(function(e,r) {
     ... do work ...
  });
});
```

but i don't know how to close the db afterwards

Comment: This is a pretty common scenario with nodejs, if you actually need to close the db, you'll need to keep a counter for 'inflight' finds and when the counter is 0, close the database.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715216/wait-for-loop-to-finish/19715317#19715317

Comment: ty @jeremy, was hoping there was something builtin or i didn't realize or could find.  will do.

Comment: Its pretty standard practice to leave the DB open the entire life of the app.

Comment: ty, I'm using it for a script but it doesn't terminate until db handle closes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Close db in the end of last function

```
db.collection('a').find().each(function(i) {
   db.collection('b').find(... use i here ...).toArray(function(e,r) {
         ... do work ...
         db.close()
  });
});
```